# Redirecting facebook's feed dialog with direct link to the post created

Tags: facebook, redirect, hyperlink

I am trying to use the direct link provided by facebook to post something on my wall. The post appears successfully on my wall. However, I can't seem to find a good way to give some feedback to the user on the successful action. I could create a webpage that says "Success" or something like that but **I really wanted to show the post after I posting it.**

In the [facebook developers reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) it says that after a successful post it puts a "post id" in the redirect link, but what should the `redirect_uri` be to use it?

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&
link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
caption=Reference%20Documentation&
description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redirect_uri` should point to your page where you will parse the `post_id` parameter out of URL arguments and do whatever you want, like redirect to the created post.

You may also want to use [`FB.ui({method:'feed'/*...*/}, callback)`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) of JS-SDK to do all the work for you, so you'll be able to pick `post_id` in `FB.ui` callback instead of manually creating Feed Dialog URL and passing `redirect_uri`.